# how to call a function using dynamic function name (parameterized) in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am able to call function in my code.. however I want to make my calling function name as variable so that it can call any function based on my variable value ..

```
reportPage.accounts()['catType']()
```

so here I want to make catType as variable, so that I can pass any value.. How to declare/call here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace the string literal with the variable, exactly as you would anywhere else.

```
var thing = 'catType';
reportPage.accounts()[thing]()
```

Comment: I think brackets after `accounts` should be deleted. Not sure that `accounts` is function, which returns a function.

Comment: @alexmac — There is nothing suggesting the that code the OP has provided doesn't work. There is no reason to think that account is not a function that returns another function.